# What does the dashed box mean on this wiring diagram?

Tags: wiring, diagram

I couldn't find an automotive mechanical stack exchange, so hope this is ok here.

This is a partial wiring diagram of the PCM on my truck (2011 Dodge Ram).  I am trying to find the Driver Unlock Relay in the vehicle but I think this is telling me it is part of the PCM circuit board.  Can anyone confim or deny?

Also, what is the meaning of the dashed box around "Front Driver Door Unlock, Driver Door Relay Control & Passenger Doors Unlock Relay"?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is pretty clear that the relay designated DOOR UNLOCK DRIVER is on the PCM board because it says: (ON PCB). On the other hand, in general, items placed in dashed boxes on  board schematics are meant to indicate that they are not on that particular board. They are put there to show how the signals are used and to guide you to where they are shown on another schematic.